# Escaping formula for Grails derived properties

Tags: postgresql, grails, grails-orm

Grails offers [derived properties](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#5.5.2.11%20Derived%20Properties) to generate a field from a SQL expression using the *formula* mapping parameter:

```
static mapping = {
    myfield formula: "field1 + field2"
}
```

I'm trying to use the formula parameter with a PostgreSQL database to make a concatenated field. The syntax is a little strange since PostgreSQL 8.4 doesn't yet support concat_ws:

```
static mapping = {
    myfield formula: "array_to_string(array[field1, field2],' ')"
}
```

The produced SQL shown with *loggingSql = true* in the DataSource config has the table prefix inserted into some strange places:

```
select table0_.field1 as field1_19_0_,
       table0_.field2 as field2_19_0_,=
       array_to_string(table0_.array[field1, table0_.field2], ' ') as formula0_0_
from test_table table0_ where table0_.id=?
```

The table prefix errantly appears before *array* but not before *field1* in the derived formula. Is there a way to escape the prefix or correct this behavior more explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an issue with parsing the formula syntax. GORM tries to insert the table prefix for unquoted expressions not followed by parens, so the ARRAY[] notation trips it up.

My solution was to define the [concat_ws function](http://okbob.blogspot.com/2009/08/mysql-functions-for-postgresql.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION concat_ws(separator text, variadic str text[])
RETURNS text as $$
SELECT array_to_string($2, $1);
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

The GORM *formula* parameter can now avoid the ARRAY[] syntax, and works as expected.

```
myfield formula: "concat_ws(' ', field1, field2)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem and solved it by adding **single-quotes** around the things that GORM was trying to prefix:

```
static mapping =
{
    dayOfYear formula: " EXTRACT('DOY' FROM observed) "
}
```

GORM then produced this, which worked:

```
select
    EXTRACT('DOY' FROM observed)  as y1_
```

This may not work in all cases, but I hope it helps somebody.